# Closed form solution to an equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}, w \in \mathbb{R}^d, y \in \{\pm 1
\}^{n}, \alpha \in (0, 1)$. Consider the equation

$$ X^{\top}(Xw-y)+\alpha \|w\|_{2}X^{\top}\operatorname{sign}(Xw-y)+\alpha\frac{\|Xw-y\|_{1}}{\|w\|_{2}}w+ \alpha^2n w = 0.$$

Note the $L_{1}$-norm in the third term. Let $s = \operatorname{sign}(X w - y) \in \{\pm 1\}^{n}$ be a $\pm 1$ vector. The term $\|Xw-y\|_{1}$ partitions $\mathbb{R}^d$ into convex cells, in each of which $s = \operatorname{sign}(X w - y)$ is constant. Then we can rewrite the above equation as

$$ X^{\top}(Xw-y)+\alpha \|w\|_{2}X^{\top}s + \alpha\frac{ s^{\top}(Xw-y)}{\|w\|_{2}}w+ \alpha^2n w = 0.$$

Is it possible to find a closed form expression for when $w$ satisfies this equation? Specifically is it possible to find the conditions under which there exists a setting of $s$ and a choice of $w$ such that the equation is satisfied?

Comment: So, there's no way to solve this?

Comment: I doubt there is closed form solution but you can solve it numerically.